# MVC request handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET maps HTTP requests to HTTP handlers based on a file name extension. I was just wondering how does it work in MVC, because in MVC we just point to the action method inside the controller. There is no extention we specify.

Then I tried to understand how handler works in MVC Application execution process from **[this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612(v=vs.100).aspx)**

But still I did not understand. Can anybody explain how handlers work in MVC and how it is different from normal ASP.NET Handlers.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, a comprehensive explanation here would be really out of scope, you should read about it to learn it in depth, and if you accept an advise, if you are able to find one, a book is generally a better resource than blogposts and the like (in my experience, as a blog post could be written by anyone who might not have a clue). Just make sure you read the reviews to find out whether a book is good or not so you won't get mislead.

Anyway, I'll try to outline the basics, without adding too much noise with the details because that would lead too far.

As others have already mentioned in their answers, in the MVC ecosystem, there is a concept called routes and routing table. Basically, what they are, is a collection of *patterns*. When a request arrives, the request header contains the requested url, such as these:

- `http://localhost:12345/`
- `http://localhost:12345/home/index`
- `http://localhost:12345/products/catalog`
- `http://localhost:12345/products/details/1`
- `http://localhost:12345/promotion`

There is a reason I've written more than one, and with different formats. Let's examine them one by one.

**The `http://localhost:12345/` example**

The first, `http://localhost:12345/` is the simplest one possible, it is usually referred to as default route. Usually this points to a parameterless `Index` action method in the `HomeController`, in the default area (that is, in "no area"). Note that both the action and the controller, as well as the area (and, well, pretty much any detail) is configurable. You make this work by adding *the default route*, but this is usually done for you by the project template. You can find it in the App_Start/RouteConfig file, it has a `name` parameter of `"Default"`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So, whenever a request comes in which no (let me say this in a primitive way) additional parts are present, they get handled by the `Index` action inside the `HomeController`. As you can see in the code above, `Index` and `HomeController` are configured in the `defaults:` parameter, it is there where you have to go to in order to change the defaults. If you instead use an action called `Welcome`, then you would need to pass this to the method above:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Welcome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Also note that despite I've written "in which no additional parts are present", by additional parts I only mean *route segments* -- for example, a query string `?param1=value1` **will not** prevent this route from being selected.

**The `http://localhost:12345/home/index` example**

This is the exact same as above. I've only included this so that you can see that even though this particular route is the default, nothing prevents you from actually specifying the controller and the action.

**The `http://localhost:12345/products/catalog` example**

The basic workings of this one is the same as the above two, except that this is not a default route, so you need to explicitly specify the controller and the action in order for your request to be routed to the appropriate controller and action. Look again at the configuration code above. You can see that there is a *url pattern* of `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` defined. You **do not need** to create a new route because this pattern can be used for this example. Compare them and you can see why:

```
http://localhost:12345/products   /catalog
                      {controller}/{action}/{id}
```

As you can see from the displacements, `products` is recognized as the controller name, `catalog` is recognized as the action name, and since `id` is given a default value of `UrlParameter.Optional`, the value of it may be omitted and the route will still be valid for the request. So as long as there exists a `ProductsController` in the default area and within it, a `Catalog` action which either has an `id` parameter, or has no parameters at all, or any existent parameter has a default value (or is nullable, in which case it will be passed null), the routing system will use this route for the request.

**The `http://localhost:12345/products/details/1` example**

Same as above, but here, `1` is mapped to the `id` segment. As long as there is a `ProductsController` in the default area, and within it, there exists a `Details` action, which either has no parameters at all (since `id` is optinal, it may be ignored), or has a parameter called `id` and if every other parameters that might be present have a default value (or can be defaulted to null - which means it is a reference type), then this route can be used for the request.

**The `http://localhost:12345/promotion` example**.

This is a special one I've included for one particular purpose. Let's assume you **do not** have a `PromotionController`. You can still define a *route pattern* as so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Promo",
  url: "promotion",
  defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Promotion" }
);
```

As you can see, here we assume you have a `ProductsController` and within it, a `Promotion` action. Whereas you could simply request the url `http://localhost:12345/products/promotion` (and it will actually work) specifying a "dedicated" route can also be done. I've added this example for the following reasons:

- So that you can see such a thing is possible
- Because there might be cases when you need it, such as:

  - The path at which a particular functionality could earlier be found, is now changed, but because your users might have bookmarked that page with the old url, you don't want them to see 404s. In this case, this route is used to "reroute" (not an HTTP Redirect, just couldn't find a better word) the old url to the new one.
  - In some cases, you do not want to expose the controller/action hierarchy. In the case of this example, simply typing "promotion" might be a little bit more telling to the user than typing "products/promotion". You can argue with this in this example, but still, there might be better examples in which case this is feasible. Also, you can use this to provide shorter urls.

And finally, let's remark a few things about the routing system as a whole.

1. There might be cases when an url *could* be mapped to more than one routes. In this case, the order in which the patterns are defined is the determining factor. The **first** one that matches the url gets picked which means that you should specify your route patterns starting with the most specific (aka with fewer or no varying parts at all). An example for a pattern with no varying parts is the last url I've written, it has a hardcoded pattern of `promotion`. You can recognize these from having no `{}`s in the pattern. The least specific (in other words, more general) ones should be at the bottom of the method. If there still are overlaps, you should rethink how you define your routes.
2. There are other things that can affect whether or not an action can be selected to serve a request. For example, the presence of `[HttpPostAttribute]` on an action method will tell the *action invoker* (and **not the routing engine**) that this method can only be used if the request is a POST request (unless an `[HttpGetAttribute]` is also applied). Note that the routing system and the so-called action invoker are two different things - you can find yourself in a situation where the routing system will find a pattern match for a route but the action invoker finds no suitable actions - for example, as above, a pattern is matched for which there is no GET handler but the request is actually an HTTP GET. This is beyond the scope of your question, but wanted to include this as a hint so that you are aware that you need to look it up. The `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` attributes mentioned above are special ones, in order to achieve such a functionality by implementing your own attributes, your attributes must derive from the `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` class.
3. As you said in your question, requests are not mapped to files but to controllers and actions. So suppose a matching route pattern is found, and the controller to use happens to be `Home(Controller)` and the action to be `Index`. What the system does (this is not the responsibility of the routing system from here on) it scans the assembly of the running application (using reflection) and enumerates all the classes inside of it. It looks for classes that fulfill certain criteria (I'm not sure about whether or not the following is 100% accurate and/or comprehensive):

   - Derives directly or indirectly from `Controller`
   - Is not abstract
   - Is public (not sure about this one)
   - Has a public constructor (not sure about this either)
   - The name is either `Home` or `HomeController` (not sure if simply `Home` works, actually it is a convention to suffix the names with the term "Controller")

If none is found, then the request cannot be fulfilled as per the matching route. If more than one are found, then the one to use cannot be determined and an error is raised.

If exactly one matching class (Controller) is found, then the system will further investigate it. It will now look for methods that:

- Are action methods, that is, their return type is `ActionResult` or a derived class (this is not required for AJAX-requests)
- Are public
- Its parameters satisfy the constraints defined by the route as discussed earlier
- Any `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`-derived attributes applied to a particular method *do not prevent* the action from being executed as per the request properties.

If no or more than one matching action methods are found, the request cannot be fulfilled and an error is raised.

If there is exactly one match, it gets invoked to fulfill the request.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination.I understood request will go thruogh routing and routing mechnism will decide which action method of which controller will serve the request.  But still could you please clear a point - where handlers are used in MVC and at what basis it is decided which handler will serve the request?

Comment: Get rid of thinking about handlers the way you do in the case of "regular" asp.net. In MVC, you do not need to care about them in most of the scenarios. Basically, the task of a handler in the MVC world is to delegate the work to a controller and its action. You can actually create and use custom handlers in MVC too but usually there is simply no need to do so. As to how it is decided which handler will serve the request take a look at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have confused with the terminologies.

MVC uses routing tables to find the route to particular View.

Just like you have `www.YourSite.com/index.aspx`, You have `www.YourSite.com/Home/Index`.

The difference is that, `in ASP.Net, you will be directly loading the .aspx file` as in the URL and `in MVC, you will go to the Home controller and look for an Index action. The Index action will then render it's view`.

Here, each view or partial view will have their ActionMethod in a controller.

**No view is rendered without a controller and action associated!**

You could have a look at [this link](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc) for further reference.

you will have a default route in the Global.asax file which will do the job.

If you have any complicated ones(with multiple parameters), You need to add them to the routing table manually. more about this is in the link.

Hope this hellps.

Comment: ASP.NET offers a few default HTTP handlers:
Page Handler (.aspx): handles Web pages
User Control Handler (.ascx): handles Web user control pages
Web Service Handler (.asmx): handles Web service pages
Trace Handler (trace.axd): handles trace functionality

Comment: @user2318170 Basically, all the events are handled by MVC itself. For the features you mentioned, have a look at [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380098/Basic-Routing-for-HttpHandler). He explains it pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse it too much

all controllers are class

all actions are methods

you are just calling the methods(functions) from address bar thats all...

the mvc handler check wither there is a method(ActionRsult) in class(Controller)
with the same name and matching params thats all

Comment: How does it know which handler will serve the request ?